# who creates the media folder in django and how to change permission rights?

Tags: python, django, nginx, permissions, file-permissions

I set up django using nginx and gunicorn. I am looking at the permission in my project folder and I see that the permission for the media folder is set to root (all others are set to debian):

`-rw-r--r-- 1 root   root    55K Dec  2 13:33 media`

I am executing all app relevant commands like `makemigrations`, `migrate`, `collectstatic`, from debian, therefore everything else is debian.

But the media folder doesn't exist when I start my app. I will be created once I upload stuff.

But who creates it and how do I change the permissions to debain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coulnd't find out who exactly is it created by, however, the permissions depend on the user (root or non root).

This means if you run the commands (for example: `python manage.py runserver`) with `sudo` or under `root` the folder gets `root` permissions which can't be edited from a non root user.